# How does ReflectionTestUtils work in the below code

Tags: java, email, testing, junit, mockito

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
    
    @PostConstruct 
    protected void init() {
        mailSender= new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("some.server.com");
        mailSender.setPort("25");
         
        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    }
    
    public void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message){   
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("someone@somewhere.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(recipient); 
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject); 
        simpleMailMessage.setText(message);
        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);        
    }
}
```

Above code is to send emails.

```
public class EmailServiceTest {
    
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
    
    @InjectMocks
    private EmailService emailService;
    
    @Mock
    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
    
    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  
    }
    
    @Test
      public void testEmail(){
        exception.expect(MailSendException.class);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(emailService, "mailSender", mailSender);
        emailService.sendEmail("me.com", "test", "this is a unit test");
        
      }
}
```

I have written a test case where I expect the mail send to fail, however I am not getting any errors
In EmailServicetest testEmail() I expect a MailSendException as the server doesnt exist. Can anyone tell me what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField` replaces `mailSender` field in emailService with your mock.

As there is no behaviour specified for `mailSender`, each method call on this mock responds with default behaviour - default value for return type is returned. For void method, method call has no effect. This is why you get no exceptions.

You need to specify expected behaviour with `Mockito.when`

On top of that:

Set `JavaMailSenderImpl.mailSender` via `@Autowired` constructor, not via `@PostConstruct` method. This way, you externalize mail server configuration and facilitate testing (for example, no need for reflection)